# Import data into tally by XML tags

Tags: java, php, .net, xml

I am trying to develop a .net program for import data into tally. And now I had a error while import the data :

> ERROR: Voucher: ID:<>, Voucher Type: Journal, Source Voucher Number: 2, Voucher Number: 1215, Date: 29-Jun-2016

Please help to find the bugs.

Comment: Can you share your code where you are getting error. How are you trying to do this.

Comment: <?xml version="1.0"?>
<ENVELOPE>
  <HEADER>
      <TALLYREQUEST>Import Data</TALLYREQUEST>
  </HEADER>
  <BODY>
      <IMPORTDATA>
          <REQUESTDESC>
          <REPORTNAME>Vouchers</REPORTNAME>
          <STATICVARIABLES>
              <SVCURRENTCOMPANY>Shiksha Financial Services India Private Limited - (From 1-Apr-2016)</SVCURRENTCOMPANY>
          </STATICVARIABLES>
          </REQUESTDESC>
  <REQUESTDATA>
<TALLYMESSAGE xmlns:UDF="TallyUDF">

Comment: <VOUCHER VCHKEY="5f4638fa-1d2e-4143-8780-ae07e1198c84-0000a5fd:00000408" VCHTYPE="Journal" ACTION="Create" OBJVIEW="Accounting Voucher View">
<DATE>20160206</DATE>
<VOUCHERTYPENAME>Journal</VOUCHERTYPENAME>
<VOUCHERNUMBER>726</VOUCHERNUMBER>
<PARTYLEDGERNAME>US20150003 Dr Led - Brilliant School&#13;&#10;</PARTYLEDGERNAME>
<EFFECTIVEDATE>20160206</EFFECTIVEDATE>
<ENTEREDBY>System</ENTEREDBY>

Comment: <ALLLEDGERENTRIES.LIST>
<REMOVEZEROENTRIES>No</REMOVEZEROENTRIES>
<ISDEEMEDPOSITIVE>No</ISDEEMEDPOSITIVE>
<LEDGERFROMITEM>No</LEDGERFROMITEM>
<LEDGERNAME>US20150003 Dr Led - Brilliant School&#13;&#10;</LEDGERNAME>
<CATEGORY>Erode Branch</CATEGORY>
<NAME>Erode </NAME>
<AMOUNT>-20413.00</AMOUNT>
</ALLLEDGERENTRIES.LIST>

Comment: <ALLLEDGERENTRIES.LIST>
<REMOVEZEROENTRIES>No</REMOVEZEROENTRIES>
<ISDEEMEDPOSITIVE>No</ISDEEMEDPOSITIVE>
<LEDGERFROMITEM>No</LEDGERFROMITEM>
<LEDGERNAME>US20150003 Loan-Anthiyur Brilliant Nursery</LEDGERNAME>
<CATEGORY>Erode Branch</CATEGORY>
<NAME>Erode </NAME>
<AMOUNT>11446.00</AMOUNT>
</ALLLEDGERENTRIES.LIST>

Comment: <ALLLEDGERENTRIES.LIST>
<REMOVEZEROENTRIES>No</REMOVEZEROENTRIES>
<ISDEEMEDPOSITIVE>No</ISDEEMEDPOSITIVE>
<LEDGERFROMITEM>No</LEDGERFROMITEM>
<LEDGERNAME>Interest Accured on School Loan</LEDGERNAME>
<CATEGORY>Erode Branch</CATEGORY>
<NAME>Erode </NAME>
<AMOUNT>8967.00</AMOUNT>
</ALLLEDGERENTRIES.LIST>

Comment: </VOUCHER>
</TALLYMESSAGE>
</REQUESTDATA>
</IMPORTDATA>
</BODY>
</ENVELOPE>

Comment: 1) Envelop 2)Voucher definition 3)Debtors ledger 4)Loan ledger 5)Interest ledger. 6)Closing tags. Thank you

Comment: You can edit your question to fill in more details. Putting data in comments is not a good place to share code.